# Drupal 7: Use current node id to dynamically generate link on page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-panels

I'm building an artgallery using Page Manager and Panels in Drupal 7.

A piece of art in the gallery is a node type and each one is related to a period of time, which is also a node type.

When viewing a page displaying a period of time, I need a link that takes the user to all the pieces of art relating to that period of time.

So I have made a view, that uses the nodeid of a timeperiod as a contextual filter, and gets all the artwork nodes, that are related to that particular timeperiod node.

The question is, when on the page for the timeperiod, how do I grab the nodeid of that particular timeperiod and dynamically generate a link to a page where the current nodeid is passed as an argument? (So that the correct pieces of art are fetched with the view).

Comment: Which template are you trying to get the node id in to? Page.tpl.php?

Comment: Have a look at the [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, it will formalise the relationship and provide the links to the referenced content out of the box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `arg(1)` in a piece of custom code to get the current node id (but only if it is a node you're on). See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7.  For instance you could easily embed your view in a template of your choice or a within a theme function like this:

```
views_embed_view('name_of_your_view', 'display_name', arg(1));
```

where the third parameter is the argument, the node id of your current (timeperiod) node. See http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.

To just place a link on that timeperiod node to that page (generated by your view) you would probably use a preprocess function in conjunction with a template (print if set). The possibilities there are uncountable, so you might need to provide further informations, where to place the link. But basically it can be achieved by using `arg(1)'.